# Can you always buy to cover?

Tags: shorting-securities

If one short sells, is there always the ability to 'buy to cover' or can there be a situation where it's not allowed by the government due to some kind of emergency, I heard in 2008 financial crisis that they temporarily banned shorting. What happens if someone already has shorted securities would that prevent them to 'buy to cover' and not be able to get out of the short?

Answer (score 1):

In 2008, the temporary ban on shorting was restricted to financial stocks.

For the most part, only a halt in the stock or a halt in the market (like today) prevents you from being able to cover a short position.  There have been a very small number of situations where it was almost impossible to buy to cover.

The classic example often cited is the Porsche's surreptitious acquisition of Volkswagen shares and derivatives prior to making  surprise announcement that it had a large stake in the company.  Supposedly, it made Volswagen the most valuable company in the world at that time.

Comment: as far as the market is considered then, 'buy to cover' is the same as 'buy' meaning. it's just the ability to be able to buy is the only factor here?

Comment: Yes, it's just a buy transaction that is "covering" an open short position (option, stock, futures contract).  Also called Buy To Close.

Comment: I like how you put "supposedly".